# how to pass checkbox checked row index to javascript from gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview and i want to pass rowindex value to javascript. I tried with following code but its not working.

In Gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"  onclick="javascript:return checkSts('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItemIndex) %>')" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In Javascript:

```
function checkSts(i) {  alert(i); }
```

Comment: plz, can you post your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type it as

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return checkSts('<%#Eval("FieldName")%>')" />
```

and work.

Alternative with `asp:checkbox`

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chBEna" onclick='<%#getCode(Container.DataItem)%>' />
```

and on code behind

```
protected string getCode(object oItem)
{
    string cPid = DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "FieldName").ToString();

    return "return checkSts('" + cPid + "')";
}
```

both checked and works.

Comment: Aristos, i wants to process everything on client side. for example if i have 100 rows i dont to go every time on server side when i click check box

Comment: @user1645200 what do you mean ? (lost you here)

Comment: Aristos, i wants to process everything on client side. for example if i have 100 rows i dont to go every time on server side when i click check box

Comment: @user1645200 Ok, now I understand that you do not understand what the code do. So simple use it and you see :) - this code is render what you going to do on client side - is not processing on code behind anything. The function I use on code behind is for rendering, because is difficult (at least I do not know how) to render this code direct.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `rowindex` of element by using `parentElement` to reach to the row in which particular elemnt is nested

eg.

```
onclick="callme(this)"

function callme(obj)
{
  obj.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex--- this wud be rowindex of the row.
}
```